# how can i implements promise interface by typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
export interface CarElement {
   bus: Promise<Int32Array>;
}
```

> error:Class "CarResult" incorrectly implements interface "Promise".
> Type "CarResult" is missing the following properties from type "Promise":
> then,catch,finally,[Symbol.toStringTag] ts(2420)

```
class CarResult implements Promise<CarElement>{
   bus:Int32Array = new Int32Array;
}
```

how should I fix the error?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you generally never do things like `class CarResult implements Promise` in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

A class cannot implement a Promise. I geuss you want to return a promise, but that would be a method defined in the class like. Example:

```
class CarResul {
   bus:Int32Array = new Int32Array;

   async CarElement(): Promise<CarElement> {
    return Promise.resolve(
     // CarElement
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: now at "return Promise.resolve", had an error.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'CarElement'

Comment: Sure because it was an example. There you have to return the real `EasyOcrElement`. I do not see that type in your example.

Comment: it worked ,thanks for your help